# if $(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})$ and $(b+\sqrt{b^2+1})$ are converse then prove that a and b are opposites

Tags: linear-algebra

$(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})\,(b+\sqrt{b^2+1})=1$ is supposed to equal: $b = -a$ but how do i get that? I've been trying to solve for like 2 days now.

Comment: Could you tell me where you saw this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, it's not standard to call numbers that multiply to $1$ "converse".

Answer (score 4):

If
$$
(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})(b+\sqrt{b^2+1})=1$$
we have
$$
a+\sqrt{a^2+1}=\sqrt{b^2+1}-b \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
$$
b+\sqrt{b^2+1}=\sqrt{a^2+1}-a \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$
$(1)+(2)$ then $a=-b$.

Answer (score 0):

**First approach.** You can do it quite directly. This is not an elegant path, but it's easy to grasp and it is reliable. Regard your equality as an equation, where $b$ is fixed and $a$ is an unknown. How would you go about solving it?

It seems that the natural thing to do is to get $\sqrt{a^2+1}$ on one side of the equation, and then square everything to get rid of the radicals. Like this:
$$
\begin{align}
a + \sqrt{a^2+1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1} + b} \\
\sqrt{a^2 + 1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1} + b} - a \\
a^2 + 1 &= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1} + b} - a\right)^2 = a^2 - \frac{2a}{\sqrt{b^2+1} + b} + \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{b^2+1} + b\right)^2} \\
\frac{2a}{\sqrt{b^2+1}+b} &= \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{b^2+1} + b\right)^2} - 1 \\
2a &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1}+b} - \sqrt{b^2+1} - b = \frac{1 - (b^2 + 1) - 2b\sqrt{b^2+1} - b^2}{\sqrt{b^2+1} + b} = 
-2b
\end{align}
$$
And therefore $a=-b$.

**Second approach.** Another way to go about the problem is to exercise your curiosity. You might try to look at the converse statement, just to see what comes out of it: is it true that whenever $a=-b$, the equality $(a + \sqrt{a^2+1})(b + \sqrt{b^2+1})=1$ holds? It this is so, then it would mean that $(a + \sqrt{a^2+1})(-a + \sqrt{a^2+1})=1$ is true for any $a$. Does it look like that's indeed the case? Yes it does, by the formula for the difference of two squares:
$$
(\sqrt{a^2+1}+a)(\sqrt{a^2+1}-a) = (\sqrt{a^2+1})^2 - a^2 = 1.
$$
So, this is always true. Can we use this equality somehow to prove the original statement? We can, but I won't do it, because it's already been done in other answers.